# Getting array aggregate of all modes for a group by result

Tags: postgresql

I have a bunch of ~600k rows of let's say owner's names (varchar) and pet type (also varchar). For each owner's name I'd like an array with the most frequent pet they have (or pets if they have an equal amount of the same pet type).

An example:

```
*owner, pet type*
alice, cat
alice, dog
bob, fish
bob, cat
bob, fish
eve, cat
eve, dog
eve, cat
eve, dog
```

Expected output:

```
alice, [cat, dog]
bob, [fish]
eve, [cat, dog]
```

My feeling is that this is some combination of 'distinct on' in an inner query with array_agg on an outer query to do the array aggregation - but I just can't get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by combining window functions and grouping:

```
select owner, array_agg(pet order by pet)
from (
  select owner, pet, dense_rank() over (partition by owner order by count(*) desc) as rnk
  from pet
  group by owner, pet
) t
where rnk = 1
group by owner
order by owner;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/MTFIQ24341

Answer (score 1):

```
with data as (
select 'alice' as owner, 'cat' pet_type
union all select 'alice' as owner, 'dog'  pet_type
union all select 'bob' as owner, 'fish' pet_type
union all select 'bob' as owner, 'cat' pet_type
union all select 'bob' as owner, 'fish' pet_type
union all select 'eve' as owner, 'cat' pet_type
union all select 'eve' as owner, 'dog' pet_type
union all select 'eve' as owner, 'cat' pet_type
union all select 'eve' as owner, 'dog' pet_type
) , getMaxPet as (select owner , pet_type
from data d1
group by owner,pet_type
having count(pet_type) = (select max(pet_count) from (select count(pet_type) as pet_count
                from data d2
                where 
                d1.owner = d2.owner
                group by owner,pet_type  ) a ) )
select owner , array_agg(pet_type)
from getMaxPet
group by owner
```

Try this, Main logic is to find all pets counts based on each user and then selects pet who is having max number.